# How to restore or add the System variable - Windows 10

Tags: ruby, environment-variables, system-variable

I've installed Ruby and in the **User Variables**, I can see that Path = C:\Ruby22-x64\bin

However, when I run *ruby* in the cmd, it says 'ruby' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I've accidentally deleted the Path in **System Variables** and I think that's why it's not working.

Could anyone guide me on how to restore or add the Path in the System Variable?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: this has been answered in http://superuser.com/questions/973153/standard-value-of-path-variable-windows-10

Answer (score 0):

The default value is:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
```